# How to stack data with python and pandas in this shape?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, append, reshape

I'm completely lost and need your help. I have N datasets each with m columns and x*N lines in a form of lists.

x = amount of subjects

N = amount of tasks

param1 & param2 = parameters that are converging

Each of the datasets consists of linear model parameters for each case for each subject

```
df_1= {'id': [1, 2], 'task': [1, 1], 'param1': [1, 2],'param2': [0.5,0.8]} 
df_1 = pd.DataFrame(df_1, columns = ['id', 'task','param1', 'param2'])

id  task    param1  param2 
1   1       1       0.5 
2   1       2       0.8

df_2= {'id': [1, 1, 2, 2], 'task': [1, 2, 1, 2], 'param1': [1.2, 3.2,
2.1, 3.2],'param2': [0.4, 1.1, 0.8, 2.2]} 
df_2 = pd.DataFrame(df_2, columns = ['id', 'task','param1', 'param2'])

id  task    param1  param2 
1   1       1.2     0.4 
1   2       3.2     1.1 
2   1       2.1     0.8 
2   2       3.2     2.2


df_3= {'id': [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2], 'task': [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3], 'param1': [1.1, 3.1, 2.2, 2.3, 3.2, 1.1],'param2': [0.35, 1.05, 0.7, 0.8, 2.2,
1.1]} 
df_3 = pd.DataFrame(df_3, columns = ['id', 'task','param1', 'param2'])

id  task    param1  param2 
1   1       1.1     0.35 
1   2       3.1     1.05 
1   3       2.2     0.7 
2   1       2.3     0.8 
2   2       3.2     2.2 
2   3       1.1     1.1
```

This trend continues to df_N until we have x * N lines in the df_N.

I need to stack all the df's in one, with some rules, so that df_final will still have x * N lines,but for each id and each task, if we have information about tasks **before this task** we will append them together, the order of the columns does not matter, the dtype of columns also does not matter, the NA values should not be 0.  Information about task should be stacked by id of person

The final result should look like this:

```
id  task    1param1 1param2 2param1 2param2 3param1 3param3 
1   1       1       0.5 
1   2       1.2     0.4     3.2     1.1 
1   3       1.1     0.35    3.1     1.05    2.2     0.7 
2   1       2       0.8 
2   2       2.1     0.8     3.2     2.2 
2   3       2.3     0.8     3.2     2.2     1.1     1.1
```

HUGE thanks for your help!

edit: sorry for long formatting, now looks like its done (this is for science).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that your final dataframe is not really keyed on `id` and `task`, but really `id` and `df_num` and then the columns are `task+param1` and `task+param2`. So really what you need to do is:

```
final_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['id','df'])
final_df.set_index(['id','df'], inplace=True)
for i, df in enumerate(datasets):
    for _,row in df.iterrows():
        final_df.loc[(int(row['id']),i+1), str(int(row['task'])) + 'param1'] = row['param1']
        final_df.loc[(int(row['id']),i+1), str(int(row['task'])) + 'param2'] = row['param2']

final_df.sort_index(inplace=True)
```

Here is what `final_df` looks like after executing the above code:

```
       1param1  1param2  2param1  2param2  3param1  3param2
id df
1  1       1.0     0.50      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN
   2       1.2     0.40      3.2     1.10      NaN      NaN
   3       1.1     0.35      3.1     1.05      2.2      0.7
2  1       2.0     0.80      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN
   2       2.1     0.80      3.2     2.20      NaN      NaN
   3       2.3     0.80      3.2     2.20      1.1      1.1
```

Comment: Wow, looks great, thank you, ill test it! Looks very smart and complex :)

Answer (score 2):

If your dataframes are in a list called `datasets` you could do the following:

```
final_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['id','task'])
for i, df in enumerate(datasets):
    final_df = final_df.merge(df, how='outer', on=['id', 'task'], suffixes=(str(i),''), sort=True)
```

Comment: This almost does the job, but the opposite one, thank you, but I am feeling that I'm still miles away from the solution.                                    This code stacks info about parameters we got from the next df's, but the goal in here is to stack all of the parameters from the previous df's, if we have them. I tried to show graphically the desired output in the image: [link](https://imgur.com/FhbDW3o)

Comment: Maybe we could concat the params 1&2 with some sign, transpose the matrix and the split the concat strings in different columns? What do you think?

Comment: Ah! I now understand what you are trying to do. Your labeling and explanation of what the final result should be were a little confusing. I am posting a separate answer with the solution you actually need.